# Cleaner way of comparing class member variables

Tags: java

I have a class with over 20 Strings and Ints.
I am comparing the same value of each member with two instances.
Not all Strings need to be compared but most.
I'm using this for all Strings in one isEqual method:

```
return instance1.getCar().equalsIgnoreCase(instance2.getCar())
            && instance1.getHouse().equalsIgnoreCase(instance2.getHouse())
            && instance1.getPet().equalsIgnoreCase(instance2.getPet())...
```

Checkstyle is saying :

Cyclomatic Complexity is 17 (max allowed is 10). (67:5) [CyclomaticComplexity]

Is there a cleaner way to compare certain member variables of the same class in two instances?
Thanks

Comment: Are you generally checking for equality?

Comment: What is the class name this method is in and what type is `instance1` and `instance2`? When you want to compare them you want to use `Objects.equals(instance1, instance2)`. The class of these variables/fields know better how to compare themself to other objects.

Comment: @akuzminykh - Just strings and int checking.

Comment: @progman I can't because I am only comparing some of the member variables. E.g. there are other strings that I know will be different but I don't care. Eg hostname and date. So I am not sure I can use object equals could I?

Comment: @DannyK If you want to compare only a subset of fields from that class, then you can't use `equals()` from that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with lots of

```
return Objects.equals( instance1.getCar(), instance2.getCar() )
      && Objects.equals( instance1.getHouse(), instance2.getHouse() )
```

or alternatively use project Lombok, annotating your class with `@EqualsAndHashCode` and then put `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` on fields you don't want to compare.

Comment: That's what I have but it's this that Checkstlye calls smelly. But I like the idea of EqualsAndHashCode, thanks I will look at that

Comment: Thank you John Smith that worked perfectly